# Upgrading Google Play Services libraries crashes on wrong meta-data tag

Tags: android, google-play-services

I recently upgraded the Google Play Services libraries in my Android app from 11.0.4 to 17.0.0. After launching the app update containing this, I'm seeing a large number of users getting this crash, mostly in the background -

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GoogleApiHandler
    Process: com.xxx.xxx.xxx, PID: 15055
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 11020000 but found 12451000.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtilLight.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source:19)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailabilityLight.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source:5)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source:94)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.GoogleApiAvailabilityCache.getClientAvailability(Unknown Source:23)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.connect(Unknown Source:216)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager.zab(Unknown Source:47)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager.handleMessage(Unknown Source:173)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.base.zap.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:8)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

1102000 corresponds to 11.0.4, and 12451000 corresponds to 17.0.0.

I checked my manifest in the android studio APK analyzer, and that declaration was correctly present in the merged manifest under the application element. I also checked the resources (resources.arsc) for google_play_services_version, and the "found" value was the expected 12451000.

I also went through the bytecode for GooglePlayServicesUtilLight, and the hardcoded "expected" value was also 12451000 rather than 1102000 like the log says.

I'm pretty sure both the "found" value and the "expected" value come from play-services-basement, with "found" coming from the declared value for google_play_services_version and referenced in its manifest, and "expected" hardcoded in GooglePlayServicesUtilLight class. How is it possible that these are different at runtime?

Is this a known issue when upgrading? It looks like most users only encounter this once. Is it possible that it's caused by the user not having an up-to-date version of Google Play Services? More than half of the users are on Android 10, though.

Is there a way to mitigate the crashes? Perhaps by catching the exception from the GoogleApiHandler thread and closing the app?

Comment: Do you have the suggested tag in the manifest?  `<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`

Comment: @MRamzan Yes, it's there when I open the APK's merged manifest. It comes in from play-services-basement's manifest.

Comment: @ayen did you managed to fix it during this time? I've encountered the same problem..

Comment: @MiraslauRachkouski No, the crash count just dropped a few days after the app update release. It was affecting most users just once, so I'm guessing it's something that happens on upgrade. I wasn't able to get confirmation of this from official sources, though.